# How to rename or creat a txt file that the user defined its name

Tags: vb.net

Hi wanted the user to create a file with the name he/she chose so later they can find it at any time but the codes I am finding to do it are usually within "" and they have a .txt in the end so I cant just set a variable for it I am kinda new to VB too so How can I make a user named txt file ?

Comment: What if they choose a name that is the same as your program? This seems dangerous.  What have you tried?  Please include that code so we might assist you in fixing it.

Comment: the names are supposed to be in numbers and I have already fixed the other bugs the names cant be the same I have lucked the ASCII keys so they cant pick other than a few numbers and words

Answer (score 0):

You can Path.Combine strings to create the file name, for example:

```
fWriter = New StreamWriter(ADirectory & "\" & TheirFileName & ".txt", False)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help I am gonna try this be back in a few mins

Comment: You mean, one can use `Path.Combine()` to glue together path parts. Remove that `Encoding.Default` or change it to `Encoding.UTF8`.

Comment: sw = New StreamWriter(Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem & "D:\vb\" & rtbCase & rtbName & ".txt")

Comment: @HereGoes this is the code I have written based on what I found on the internet and what I got from your code but its not working can you please edit this ?

Comment: BC30452 Operator '&' is not defined for types 'FileSystemProxy' and 'String'

Comment: My.Computer.FileSystem isn't a string so you can use it in the Patch.Combine.  Looks like you could just do sw = New StreamWriter(Path.Combine( "D:\vb\" & rtbCase & rtbName & ".txt")

Comment: This is not how [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) works. Please, see the Docs about its functionality.